# Reduce complexity in this database design

Tags: database, database-design

The database structure is like this : each user has create their list , and have a access right assign:

For example

```
table: user
attribute: UserID

table: list
attribute: ListID

table: user_list
attribute: ListID,UserID, Rights
```

There are two kind of rights :read , edit

Everything work fine until i have a rights call public ( everyone can edit)
So that if i have 100 member with 10 list, i have to create 1000 userID - Rights: edit rows

that is incredibly increase in scale.

How to solve this:

1)Create separate  table named public and put the ListID in it?

2) Store the row as ListID , null UserID, and with Rights 'Public'?

Which method is better? Thank you.

Comment: If everyone can edit, why do you need to check if the edit right exists at all?

Comment: You are correct . So if i want to add 'public ' list , i just have to add *****ListID***,UserID, Rights into user_list table? or doing is seprately? or check the difference between user_list and list? Thank you.

Comment: for example , using select List.* from List, User_List where User_List.ListID <> List.ListID  to get those public list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm completely clear on your situation, but...

If you want to efficiently make a list public, why don't you just create an `IsPublic` field in your list table. Check that when the list is public. If a list IsPublic you don't need to check for user specific rights.

If you are concerned with too many rows in your user_list table, you can set it up with the fields:

`UserID`, `ListID`, `CanEdit`, `CanRead`

I would only do that if the number of User rights is not likely to keep growing. And I'm not sure what the difference in performance will be.